# Is there a way to force Bind9/Named to always request recursion?

Tags: dns, bind, nameserver

From what I can see, RD bit is set on queries only when the resolver is using a forwarder. If it uses a hint or a master record it does not set the RD bit. 
I know this is configured so that nameservers won't be burdened by queries but I'm setting this up for a course.

Would there be a way to modify the named daemon or Bind to always set RD bit?